# Filtering MySQL Select based on joined table's fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. Created as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE item (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    value VARCHAR(64),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)

CREATE TABLE tag (
    name VARCHAR(32),
    item_id INT /* id of element in item table */
)
```

I have a select statement that returns a list of elements in the 'item' table along with all the elements of the 'tag' table linking to that table. It is filtered on the contents of the item.value field.

```
SELECT id,value,GROUP_CONCAT(tag.name) FROM item
LEFT JOIN tag ON tag.item_id = id
WHERE value LIKE '%test%'
```

All good so far. Now I want to do the same but get a list of all the item table elements with a certain tag associated with it. So I replace the WHERE query with

```
WHERE tag.name='test'
```

This gives me a list of all the 'item' elements which have the tag 'test' but the grouped tag list that come along with it only includes the tag 'test'.

How do I get a list of all the elements of the table 'item' which have tag 'test' along with the full group tag list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should have a `GROUP BY` in your original query:

```
SELECT i.id, i.value, GROUP_CONCAT(tag.name)
FROM item i LEFT JOIN
     tag t
     ON t.item_id = i.id
WHERE i.value LIKE '%test%'
GROUP BY i.id, i.value
```

To get only rows that have a certain tag, add:

```
HAVING SUM(t.name = 'test') > 0
```

after the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Lack of GROUP BY was a typo, but the HAVING I hadn't tried and it seems to work, cheers

Comment: Seems like I can also use HAVING SUM(t.name = 'test') = 0 to catch items without the tag which solves another of my issues where it wouldn't return items with no tags on a NOT clause. Cheers